# Radgrid batch editing with columngroup

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I'm using 2013.2.611.40 Telerik RadGrid.

I'm trying to use Batch editing mode with a GridTemplateColumn. If I specify ColumnGroup property, when the cell is clicked a JavaScript error is raised in _isColumnEditable (Unable to get property _data of undefined or null reference). If ColumnGroup property is removed all is working fine and edit textbox is shown.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="MyGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Skin="Simple" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowMultiRowSelection="true"   OnPreRender="GridLastPhase_PreRender"   OnNeedDataSource="GridLastPhase_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="GridLastPhase_ItemDataBound">  
<ClientSettings>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" SaveScrollPosition="true" />
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="99%" EditMode="Batch">
        <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" OpenEditingEvent="Click" />
        <ColumnGroups>
            <telerik:GridColumnGroup Name="LQP1" HeaderText="Last Q Phase 1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </ColumnGroups>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" ShowFilterIcon="false" FilterControlWidth="100%" UniqueName="LQP1_PHASE_DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Phase" DataType="System.String" DataField="LQP1_PHASE_DESCRIPTION" SortExpression="LQP1_PHASE_DESCRIPTION" ColumnGroupName="LQP1" HeaderStyle-Width="110px" ItemStyle-Width="110px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLQP1_PHASE" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LQP1_PHASE_DESCRIPTION")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLQP1_PHASE" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LQP1_PHASE_DESCRIPTION")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with latest version of Telerik controls.